# Which filesystems are better for serving php code (via apache2) on amazons EBS?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, amazon-ec2, filesystems, amazon-ebs

I have an Ubuntu EC2 instance on amazon.
The instance has an apache2 webserver serving php5 code.
I'm using APC for op-code caching, Zend Framework as my framework, and Doctrine 2.2 as my ORM.

EDIT START:
I know there are other bottlenecks, however I am asking specifically regarding the php files aspect.
I'm using memcache for db caching and configuration files caching (if any); I'm using a CDN for static files serving; And I'm well aware of the wait for external responses such as facebook api, etc..
EDIT END;

Which filesystems are better for serving php code ?

Answer (score 1):

The filesystem you use should not matter. Your bottleneck will be something other, such as database, some external resource your scripts will query, or something completely else.

Comment: I've edited the question. The question was specifically regarding the php files loading.

Comment: My comment still remains. A simple fopen() of your PHP files is not very performance intensive stuff to do. Everything else after that is up to PHP and the upper layers anyway, and has nothing to do with the filesystem of your choice.

Comment: So choosing between xfs, ext3 and ext4 will have no effect whatsoever on the performance of my site ? (if that is the only difference)

Comment: Correct, it will have no effect whatsoever.